# Is there a way to pass variables to a URL from an HTML form submission?

Tags: urlencode

I have a Google Docs spreadsheet that I would like customers to be able to query in a roundabout way.  Essentially, here is a working lookup from my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCp5h0bMr3bnjU7OslbwjMyT-qc5-mt10IEjM7izSmg/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,+B,+C,+D,+E,+F,+G,+H+WHERE+D+CONTAINS%20985253

What I want to do is set up a form where that number at the end of the link (the 985253) is a user input and once they hit submit, it attaches that number to the end of the URL and pulls up the page.

I saw a tutorial on tagging an input onto the end of a URL that I followed, but the problem I'm having is the encoding that alters the link to the point that it doesn't work.

This is what I tried:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCp5h0bMr3bnjU7OslbwjMyT-qc5-mt10IEjM7izSmg/gviz/tq" method="GET">

<input type="text" name="tqx=out:html&tq=select A, B, C, D, E, F, G,H WHERE D CONTAINS "/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

And it produces:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCp5h0bMr3bnjU7OslbwjMyT-qc5-mt10IEjM7izSmg/gviz/tq?tqx%3Dout%3Ahtml%26tq%3Dselect+A%2C+B%2C+C%2C+D%2C+E%2C+F%2C+G%2CH+WHERE+D+CONTAINS+=

It encodes the "," "=" and "&", where I'm not sure how to pass those on to the final URL lookup without encoding them.

There's probably a much easier way to do this that I haven't considered.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to break it up like this:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCp5h0bMr3bnjU7OslbwjMyT-qc5-mt10IEjM7izSmg/gviz/tq" method="GET">

<input type="hidden" name="tqx" value="out:html"/>
<input id="tq" type="hidden" name="tq" value="select A, B, C, D, E, F, G,H WHERE D CONTAINS "/>
<input id="query" type="text"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

You can't really avoid the url escaping of the ',', but the server will have no trouble unescaping it.

To append the number to the tq value, you'll need to use a bit of javascript. For simplicity, I'll use jquery:

```
$(function() { 
    $('form').on('submit', function() { 
       $('#tq').val( $('#tq').val() + $('#query').val() ); 
    });
});
```

Comment: So something updated somewhere and the above solution no longer works.  An acceptable query now pulls up everything on the spreadsheet under the specified columns.  I couldn't find any changes to Google's search parameters that would cause this to happen and I'm curious if anyone has an ideas?

Comment: So far, it looks like it happened when Drive took over google docs and turned from the spreadsheets.google.com program to docs.google.com and lost the ability to properly access JSON data via gviz.  Still looking for a workaround.